# How do I link a CSS folder and an image folder in Eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse

I have a directory like this in Eclipse:

```
SimpleServletProject
     webontent
       >> images
           sep2.jpg
           etc.
       >> css
       >> MetaINF
       >> WebINF
            index.html
            login.html
```

The images and CSS are two folders where the images and CSS files are kept. In the CSS folder I have a login.css file.

I want to give the path of the image which is in images folder. The css code is:

```
background-image:url("/images/sep2.jpg");
```

What should be the path?

Answer (score 1):

Please try following in your css file. This should work for you.

```
background-image: url("../images/sep2.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background: url("/images/sep2.jpg");` instead. That should give you the correct path for your project. Otherwise we need some more code to identify the problem